# javascript console gotchas ? what are those values returned by setTimeout in console?

Tags: javascript, console, settimeout

When running the following code in console

```js
var ajout1 = function(number) {
  number = number || 100;
  console.log(number + 1);
}

setTimeout(ajout1, 1000);
setTimeout(ajout1(500), 2000); // evaluates immediately and returns nothing but this is "by design" to show how NOT to write your timeout
setTimeout(function() {
  ajout1(1000)
}, 3000);
```

one may expect the following result

```
t+1: 101
t+2: 501
t+3: 1001
```

If you look more closely you'll see that t2 will be immediately evaluated and so will not wait 2 second before returning. (This is "by design". It teaches (me) how not to write a timeout). So the expected output becomes:

```
t+0: 501
t+1: 101
t+3: 1001
```

In fact what I really get is

```
t+0: 501
t+0: <X
t+1: 101
t+3: 1001
```

With X a ever growing value.
I think X is the timerid so I rewrote my code as

```
var t1=setTimeout(ajout1,1000);
var t2=setTimeout(ajout1(500),2000);// no good
var t3=setTimeout(function(){ajout1(1000)},3000);
```

now the output is

```
t+0: 501
t+0: <undefined
t+1: 101
t+3: 1001
```

If i evaluate t1,t2,t3 their values are X+1, X+2, X+3. So i guess my bet X was the timer id is right.
My question is why do the console outputs the value of only 1 counter id instead of the three ? Why did I get a "undefined" value returned.

I tested in Chrome and Edge console with the same results

Comment: One major thing that stands out is settimeout's first argument is supposed to be a function which you pass correctly in T1 and T3. But T2 you aren't passing a function, you are passing the results of a function as it is immediately being evaluated.

Comment: setTimeout returns an id of the timer instance....  NOt sure what you are expecting to happen. You can not return from an asynchronous call and your code is not returning anything....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What's happening in your second `setTimeout()`?

```
setTimeout(ajout1(500)/*evaluates immediately and returns nothing*/,2000);
```

And then, that code looks like this:

```
setTimeout(undefined,2000); //undefined, because ajout1(500) didn't return anything
```

and then

```
setTimeout("undefined",2000); //Coerced to string
```

...and 2 seconds later...

```
eval("undefined") //Altough not really eval, but similar to it.
```